# Creating or later adding new field parallel to "_id" or "_source"

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to create or later add new field that is in the same level (i.e., parallel to) standard top-level fields like `_id`, `_type`, `_source` etc.? Please note that I am not looking to create those new fields in JSON content that is under `_source`.

**Just an example:** In the following content in ES, can I re-ingest new field say `_location`:

Before update/re-ingestion:

```
{
   "_index": "my_index",
   "_type": "twitter_stream",
   "_id": "1234567890",
   "_score": 1.0,
   "_source": {<JSON twitter data content>}
}
```

After update/re-ingestion:

```
{
   "_index": "my_index",
   "_type": "twitter_stream",
   "_id": "1234567890",
   "_score": 1.0,
   "_location": "Miami",
   "_source": {<JSON twitter data content>}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these are document's special fields. User-defined fields can only be added to `_source`, by adding them to index mapping.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful